# How can I write a continuous if statement that fires until a blank cell is reached?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to write an IF statement or a macro for calculating total amounts based on an hourly rate.

For example I have about 54 columns of data per person and am trying to the a code to do the following:

Column E*(Column H)-(Column F) + Column G*(Column J)-(Column H) and so on but I want the code to stop when a blank cell is reached so the formula doesn't do amount*(blank cell - date) yielding a vastly large negative number.

Here is my code without an IF statement or a macro:

```
=(C2*(F2-D2)*24+E2*(H2-F2)*24+G2*(J2-H2)*24+I2*(L2-J2)*24+K2*(N2-L2)*24+M2*(P2-N2)*24+O2*(R2-P2)*24+Q2*(T2-R2)*24+S2*(V2-T2)*24+U2*(X2-V2)*24+W2*(Z2-X2)*24+Y2*(AB2-Z2)*24+AA2*(AD2-AB2)*24+AC2*(AF2-AD2)*24+AE2*(AH2-AF2)*24+AG2*(AJ2-AH2)*24+AI2*(AL2-AJ2)*24+AK2*(AN2-AL2)*24+AM2*(AP2-AN2)*24+AO2*(AR2-AP2)*24+AQ2*(AT2-AR2)*24+AS2*(AV2-AT2)*24+AU2*(AX2-AV2)*24+AW2*(AZ2-AX2)*24+AY2)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using helper columns (one for each step in your sum eg `Column E*(Column H)-(Column F)` = 1 step) and then use `=SUM()` to sum up all helper columns. This way you can easily use a `=IF()` function in each step to check if any of the 3 cells is empty and if so eg return 0, so it doesn't blow up your sum. That would be an easy workaround only using formulas.

Comment: I would look at a for next loop with a step of 3, to `range("e1").End(xlToRight).Column` and using `offset` and `address` build this up.  Where E1 would be E<ROW NUMBER>

Comment: Not sure how it would be in relation to length, but you could use something like `NOT(ISBLANK(A1))*24` to replace the 24's if A1 is blank, it will be 0, if A1 is populated, it will be 24?  Reading each section as being `AO2*(AR2-AP2)*24`

Comment: I am too new to post images but I did upload this table of data. The 24s are to turn the time difference into hours for the other formulas I need to run off the total value im trying to calculate. https://i.postimg.cc/sDcgjsNK/Capture.png